# Custom Post Type and API REST is not working

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

I have created a custom post type called 'customers'. I'm registering step by step as the documentation says. But when I make a call to the rest api, it just returns a 404 response. See the code below:

```
add_action('init', 'customer_post_type');
function customer_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x('Customers', 'customers'),
        'singular_name'       => _x('Customer', 'customers'),
        'menu_name'           => __('Customers', 'customers'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Customer', 'customers'),
        'all_items'           => __('All Customers', 'customers'),
        'view_item'           => __('View Customer', 'customers'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Customer', 'customers'),
        'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'customers'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit Customer', 'customers'),
        'update_item'         => __('Update Customer', 'customers'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search Customer', 'customers'),
        'not_found'           => __('Not Found', 'customers'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('Not found in Trash', 'customers'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __('Customers', 'customers'),
        'description'         => __('Customer news and reviews', 'customers'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => false,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-desktop',
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'rest_base'           => 'customer',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Post_Controller'
    );

    register_post_type('customer', $args);
}
```

the urls that I am testing for, are: `/wp-json/wp/v2/customers` and `/wp-json/wp/v2/customer`

Comment: This might not fix the full issue, but I would recommend registering the post type (next-to-last line of your code) as singular `customer` rather than `customers` plural as the "s" may be throwing something off. You'll probably need to `unregister_post_type()` first to completely remove the CPT and then re-register with the new name.

Comment: @WebElaine thanks for advice, but It does not work yet :(

Comment: the class `WP_REST_Post_Controller` doesn't exists. I think that it would be better to not define `rest_controller_class` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in function.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_customer_cpt' );
  function my_customer_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Customers', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Customer', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Customers', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Customer', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Customer', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Customer', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Customer', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Customer', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Customer', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Customers', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Customers', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Customers:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No customers found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No customers found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'customer' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'rest_base'          => 'customers-api',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'customer', $args );
}
```

Then hit the url http://yourdomian.com/wp-json/wp/v2/customers-api

If result not showing
then simply hit the http://yourdomian.com/wp-json url
then check the routes and search the rest_base name in  it 'customers-api'

Make sure you have post in customer post type.

Comment: Please explain why your code is better than original.

Comment: when i run your code it throw an error .
Check my args and compare with your code.
you can understand.
or change your rest-base.
it gives you perfect result.